# How to create K8S cluster with non-root user?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

How to create K8S cluster with non-root user?
Include..
etcd,
flannel or Calico,
K8S API,
kubelet....etc

Regards

Asura

Comment: Off-topic, this question should be adressed to https://www.serverfault.com Stack overflow is about troubleshooting software development issues, usually with source code.

Comment: It's also just way too broad and likely not possible. You need to install these applications on the host and in some cases listen on privileged ports, modify iptables, etc. You need root access for this.

Comment: any possibility with equivalent user ?

Comment: @andy-shinn is right. However, I believe that root privilege is only needed for populating iptables. All the other functionality of k8s and its accompanying services don't explicitly require root. For eg. To create docker containers, the user just needs to be in the docker group. If you can find a way not to use iptables, you might have a winner. I haven't verified this btw. This is purely based on my experience with building k8s clusters.

Answer (score 0):

After Docker 19.03, [which can be installed as rootless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54521566/6309), you also have the experiment [**rootless-containers/usernetes**](https://github.com/rootless-containers/usernetes):

> Kubernetes installable under $HOME, without the root privileges

That comes with:

> - Moby (dockerd)
> - Kubernetes
>
>   - dockershim
>   - CRI-O
>   - containerd
> - Multi-node CNI
>
>   - Flannel (VXLAN)